# Linq’s Deferred Execution with string

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two functions `func1()` and `func2()`. Both these functions are using LINQ query. I have a question about why both functions are not following the same approach. Why one is producing an empty result and other one is not and vice-versa.

```
static void func1()
{
    IEnumerable<char> s = "I am Tommy Shelby";

    var query = s.Where(x => x != 'a');
    s = "";

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        Console.Write(item);
    }
}

static void func2()
{
    List<int> num = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    var query2 = num.Where(x => x % 2 == 0);

    num.Clear();

    foreach (var item in query2)
    {
        Console.Write(item);
    }
}
```

Currently :

```
func1() -> I m Tommy Shelby
func2() ->
```

Can someone help me understand how Linq deferred execution is happening in one and not in the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that strings are immutable.

That means the first variable holds a copy and a new assignment creates a new variable in memory.

Lists are reference types here, so both reference the same thing, so if you change one the other sees that change, too.

If you did `.ToList()` before clearing, you would still see the numbers because `.ToList()` creates a new copy of the list.